# getting error java.lang.NullPointerException after crawling many pages

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, web-crawler

I was trying to crawl imdb featured films from the advanced title search page (http://www.imdb.com/search/title?count=250&title_type=feature&view=simple), this is part of my code:

```
for(int start=1; start < 295378; start+=250)

    try {
        String baseUrl = "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?start="+start+";count="+count+"&title_type=feature&view=simple";  
        org.jsoup.Connection con = Jsoup.connect(baseUrl).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21");
        con.timeout(30000).ignoreHttpErrors(true).followRedirects(true);
        Response resp = con.execute();
        Document doc = null;
        if (resp.statusCode() == 200) {
            doc = con.get();                                      

            Elements myElements = doc.getElementsByClass("results").first().getElementsByTag("table");

            Elements trs = myElements.select(":not(thead) tr");
```

everything worked well till number 100239 where I got this error :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at featuredfilms.cinemamovies.main(cinemamovies.java:44)
```

the code still works for movies from number 1 to 100238, and just not working after!
pardon if this is something obvious, since I am new in Crawling and also in java. I appreciate if someone kindly inform me why I get this error and how can I fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: NullPointerException is Thrown when trying to access something uninitialized. Check What is there

Comment: sites like imdb usually don't like it to be crawled. Probably they popped up a sort of captcha-page to avoid being crawled too easily

Comment: line 44 is is : Elements myElements = doc.getElementsByClass("results").first().getElementsByTag("table");  but I dont think it is null :(

Comment: @donfuxx: you mean they may blocked me?:(  I just wanted these data to test my recommeder system algorithm that is my research field..

Comment: What would happen if there were no results?  Would `doc.getElementsByClass("results").first()` be null?  If so, that's your problem.

Comment: @DavidWallace: I checked the html code of the page, it cojntains it : <table class="results">
<tr> <th...... </th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th colspan=2></th>
  <th>User Rating</th>
  <th>Num Votes</th>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td class="number">1.</td>
<td class="title"><a href="/title/tt2015381/">Guardians of the Galaxy</a>
    <span class="year_type">(2014)</span><br>

Comment: Mona, is it possible that there's something on the page _before_ that particular table, that also has a CSS class of `results`?  Maybe `first()` isn't actually returning this table.  I'm guessing wildly, of course.

Comment: Mona, is there any chance you can set this up so that it only retrieves this one page, and then step through it with a debugger?  That is what I would try if I were faced with this problem.

Comment: @DavidWallace: I checked before this particular table and there were nothing that has css class of results.

Comment: @DavidWallace I checked also like what u said *only for this page), the result was the same :(

Comment: OK, but did you step through with the debugger?  Were you able to get the debugger to tell you exactly which expression was null?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably that after a certain number of elements the DOM structure that's returned is different from the previous pages, presumably because it contains fewer elements.

I'd suggest splitting up this line into separate variables and method invocations to track down which of these chained statements is returning `null` in your case.

```
Elements myElements = doc.getElementsByClass("results").first().getElementsByTag("table");
```

Maybe something like this would work (I'm not sure about the types):

```
Elements elementsByClass = doc.getElementsByClass("results");
Element firstResult = elementsByClass.first();
Elements myElements = firstResult.getElementsByTag("table");
```

You can then easily add null-safety checks when you find out what statement is returning `null` in this case.

**EDIT:**

If you view this link to see what happens when you get to the largest numbers, it explains why the table.results element doesn't appear in your case:

http://www.imdb.com/search/title?at=0&count=250&sort=moviemeter,asc&start=295250&title_type=feature&view=simple

Comment: I did what you said and now this one returns null: Elements myElements = firstResult.getElementsByTag("table");

Comment: I saw the html code of the page for this url: http://www.imdb.com/search/title?start=100239;count=250&title_type=feature&view=simple    , the table class = results has the same structure as the ones that I could crawl before ...

Comment: yes, but if you see this link : http://www.imdb.com/search/title?at=0&count=250&sort=moviemeter,asc&start=100239&title_type=feature&view=simple  there are enough data but still it does not work..:(